# How do I generate dynamic and static libraries from OpenSSL?

Tags: configuration, openssl, shared-libraries, static-libraries

From this [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki... I understand that when you use the `shared` option you get a shared object and when you use `no-shared`, you only get the static library.

How can I get the static library and the shared object building OpenSSL only once?

Comment: We updated the wiki: [Compilation and Installation | Configure Options](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options). That information should have been clearly stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared` is the default, and results in both shared and static libraries
being built. Only if you specify `no-shared` will the shared libraries *not* be built.